# How to export CSV from Business Object report?

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I understand that from Business Objects client I have an option to export to "CSV (data only)", but my understanding is that, such an export will not care about the report but just dump the raw universe data.

Isn't there any single way to be able to export the *report* "view" to CSV ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you included the SDK tag? Are you looking for a way to do this through the SDK or through the GUI interface?

Comment: Basically considering all the options, from gui to any "C" level interface..

Comment: I've updated my answer to include API information. As of BI4, most APIs are implemented in REST and are thus language-independent.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the version of BusinessObjects you're working on.

Originally, the CSV export only looked at the Web Intelligence (I assume you're referring to that particular client) *microcube*, meaning the raw data retrieved from the data provider(s), and disregards any formatting, filters, aggregations, … you may have specified on your report.

## GUI

However, you know have the option to export a report (so not the whole document) as a *CSV Archive*, which results in a Zip file containing a CSV for the active report at the time of export.

I'm referring to **BI 4.1 SP05**, previous versions may have this option as I'm not sure when it was introduced.

[image: Export to CSV archive]

## API

Using the RESTful API that is available in BI4, you can also export a report to CSV. In this case, the actual CSV file will be returned instead of an archive.

Remember that in order to use the RESTful API, you need to have a WACS server in your BusinessObjects environment, running the RESTful API service. You cannot deploy the REST API on an external Java application server.

For more information, have a look at the section [Exporting a Report in Listing Mode](http://help.sap.com/saphelpiis_sbo41sp5wi-sdk/frameset.htm?7da1bf3a6f701014aaab767bb0e91070.html) (SDK information for BI 4.1 SP05).

## Remarks

A *report* is a tab within a document; documents however are often (incorrectly) referred to as reports.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be an improvement but I need to confirm version at customer site. Do you know if the csv archives can also be used with scheduled reports for ftp delivery? Thanks

Comment: No, not through scheduling, as you'll export the complete document and not a single report. Thus, the CSV format will again be just the data and not the report content.